# css 2 column layout

Tags: css, layout

I have a basic two column CSS layout, the CSS looks like

```
#sidebar {
    width:100px;
}
#main {
    margin-left:100px;
}
```

And some sample html

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="sidebar">some sidebar content</div>
  <div id="main">some main content</div>
</div>
```

This works, but it seems repetitive and error prone that the sidebar width needs to match the main's margin-left value. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `float` property on `#sidebar`:

```
#sidebar {
    width:100px;
    float: left;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/HTqHJ/1/)

---

However, using the above method, if the content of `#main` causes its height to extend below `#sidebar`, [it will wrap under the sidebar](http://jsfiddle.net/HTqHJ/3/). To avoid this, use the `display:table-cell` property:

```
#sidebar, #main {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/HTqHJ/4/)

Comment: If the main content is longer than the sidebar content and wraps, the wrapping seems to end up under the sidebar...

Comment: @JeffStorey. Try adding `display:table-cell` to both `#sidebar` and `#main`: http://jsfiddle.net/HTqHJ/2/

Answer (score 2):

**CSS**

```
#sidebar { width:100px; float: left; }
#main { float: right; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="sidebar">my stuff</div>
    <div id="main">some main content</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

I recommend [960.gs](http://www.960.gs) or [BlueprintCSS](http://www.blueprintcss.org) for basic-html/css styling.

Comment: oh - that's right. Just 'float: right;' J4I: Maybe you should have a look at 960gs ( http://www.960.gs ) or at BlueprintCSS ( http://www.blueprintcss.org ).

Comment: thanks. it looks like using display:table-cell as suggested by @JSW189 laid it out as I was expecting

Comment: ic - anyways you should have a look at the mentioned css-frameworks. They are easy to use and understand.

Answer (score 0):

You may nest `sidebar` inside `main` giving `main` a padding left and `sidebar` a -ve margin.

```
#content{
    width: 100%;
}
#sidebar, #main{
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
#sidebar{
    width: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
    margin-left: -100px;
}
#main{
    padding-left: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
}

<div id="content">
    <div id="main">
        <div id="sidebar">some sidebar content</div>some main content
    </div>
</div>
```

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zz6rr/)*** is the working demo.